# Check if array entry was already exists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-programming

I have a rather simple question: How to check for an (int) array, whether the current entry array[i] was already assigned or not.

It is a dynamic programming task, where I store results for sub-tasks in an array. Thus the array is filled continuously.

I tried: `if(a[i] != null) do stuff;` but I got an error that "!=" is a bad operator in this case.

What would be the best(robust) solution to check this?

Comment: This is hard to understand, could you share an example ?

Comment: Primitive arrays cannot contain `null`, so the default value for `int[]` element is `0`. You can't know whether an element was assigned `0`, or if nothing was assigned yet. In some cases of dynamic programming you may want to assign a marker value such as `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to mark an "uninitialized" element, especially if you're doing comparisons.

Comment: `int` is a primitive data type in Java. Therefore it cannot be null. Hence `!= null` doesn't make sense for `int`.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is an `int` array, you can't ask this:

```
if (a[i] != null)
```

Because an `int` value cannot be `null`. In an empty `int` array, the uninitialized positions will have `0` as value. Maybe this will work for your use case?

```
if (a[i] != 0)
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, then consider explicitly initializing the array with a different value (for example: `-1`), at the beginning of your program, and testing against it in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

(a[i] != null) is an error for the int type. This is because int is a primitive type and cannot be null. As explained in another answer and some comments, you can fill the array with a set value such as -1 or Integer.MIN_VALUE which would flag an unused element.

If you need a value that can be null and passed as an object, perhaps an array of Integer will do.

It is initialized almost the same:

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[N];  // N is a constant indicating the length of the array
```

This creates an array that can hold Integer objects, all of which are initialized to null. You can put an Integer into the array with:

```
a[i] = new Integer(x);
```

This will work fine in your if statement:

```
if (a[i] != null) {...do something...}
```

will work fine.

Comment: Don't use the `Integer` constructor (which is [deprecated in newer Java versions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(int))). Use the `valueOf` method to leverage the `Integer` cache.

Comment: There will be a performance penalty for using `Integer` instead of `int`, and all just for allowing `null` inside the array. It makes more sense to choose an `int` for marking uninitialized values, IMHO.

Comment: The performance penalty is fairly small, or so I've read. Thet are highly optimized. There are other advantages of being an object. For one thing, they can be held in the standard collections classes.